# md-divider (mat-divider) is not showing in angular material2

Tags: angular, angular-material

I use `<md-divider>`, like `<hr>`.
I thought it's ok with using like `<hr>`.
However, `<md-divider>` is sometimes not showing.

I used `<md-divider>` in the `<md-card>`, but `<md-divider>` is not shown.
Should I only use `<md-divider>` in `<md-list>`?

If someone has the same issue with me, please share your experience to solve this issue.

Here's my code.

```html
<div class="card-height" fxLayoutAlign="center center">
  <md-card fxFlex="30" fxLayout="column">
    <md-card-title>Sign in</md-card-title>
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSignin()">
      <md-card-content>
        <div class="form-group">
          <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="E-mail" formControlName="email">
            <md-hint>
              <span class="invalid" [hidden]="myForm.controls['email'].pristine || !myForm.controls['email'].errors?.required">Required</span>
              <span class="invalid" [hidden]="myForm.controls['email'].errors?.required || !myForm.controls['email'].errors?.email">This doesn't appear to be a valid email address.</span>
              <span class="invalid" [hidden]="!myForm.controls['email'].errors?.pattern">Email address is not correct.</span>
            </md-hint>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
          <md-input-container>
            <input mdInput placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" type="password" fxLayoutAlign="center">
            <md-hint>
              <span class="invalid" [hidden]="myForm.controls['password'].pristine || !myForm.controls['password'].errors?.required">Required</span>
            </md-hint>
          </md-input-container>
        </div>
      </md-card-content>
      <md-card-actions>
        <a [routerLink]="['/forget-password']">Do you forget your password?</a>
        <button md-button color="accent" type="submit">Login</button>
      </md-card-actions>
    </form>

  </md-card>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm having the same issue, on github someone suggested moving `md-divider`, tried deleting the `flex` part just to see if that's the problem. Nothing seems to solve this issue. If you have better luck, post it.

Answer (score 9):

## Update Feb 18

The MatDivider was moved to its own [module](https://material.angular.io/components/divider/api):

```
import {MatDividerModule} from '@angular/material/divider';
```

---

## Outdated Answer

The `<md-divider>` is part of the `MdListModule`. If you want to use it, you need to import the `MdListModule` in your component's module and have at least `<md-list></md-list>` somewhere in your template. If you're not using lists, importing the whole module for the divider is probably overkill. Just reuse `<hr>` with your own styles like:

```
hr {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, .12);
  width: 100%
}
```

see [Material List Directives](https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/69c9dacf86690ffa1ae3fc3873d030016d96d6b0/src/lib/list/list.ts)

Comment: Note that as of the current version, this is no longer true: https://github.com/angular/material2/pull/5862

Comment: @Jules Thanks for the hint, I have updated the answer.

Comment: So now is <mat-divider> and you can use it on it's own (outside the md-list) https://material.angular.io/components/divider/overview

Comment: no need for /devider. you can import it like this: import { MatDividerModule } from '@angular/material';
it can save code lines if you import more modules from angular material.

Answer (score 8):

This helped me.

```
mat-divider {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Some details:
It was an Angular component with the following HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
    <!---some header text-->

    <div class="content">
    <!---some crappy content-->
    </div>

    <mat-divider></mat-divider>   

    <div class = "actions">
        <!--couple of buttons-->
    </div>    
</div>
```

And here is a CSS file:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0 15px;
    align-items: flex-start;
}

.content {
    margin: 0 15px;
}

mat-divider {
    width: 100%;
}

.actions {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-start;
    margin: 0px 15px;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**UPDATED**: Try mat-divider instead of md-divider

Try this css style.

```
md-divider {
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
}
```

Comment: Now: mat-divider

Answer (score 0):

```
import { MdListModule } from '@angular/material';

imports: [
    MdListModule
],

<md-list><md-divider></md-divider></md-list>
```